# Set width in Grid MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am working on migrating xamarin form application to MAUI.
I need to set data grid column width.

```
 <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="" Width="45" SortingEnabled="False" IsSelectAll="True" >
    <helpers:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelectAllEnabled}" Margin="16,0,0,0" />         </DataTemplate>
    </helpers:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
 </helpers:DataGridColumn>
```

```
public class DataGridColumn : BindableObject, IDefinition
{
     #region bindable properties
public static readonly BindableProperty WidthProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Width), typeof(GridLength), typeof(DataGridColumn), new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star),
propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => { if (o != n) (b as DataGridColumn)?.OnSizeChanged(); });
public GridLength Width
 {
get => (GridLength)GetValue(WidthProperty);
set => SetValue(WidthProperty, value);
  }
```

Getting below error

> No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Width", or mismatching type between value and property.

Please help

Comment: `Width` is type `GridLength`, but you are passing in an int value

Comment: @Jason this is working fine in xamarin.forms but in Maui giving error. How I can pass GridLength type data?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0#rows-and-columns

Comment: Just because something worked in XF does not guarantee it will have the same behaviour in .NET MAUI, Use GridLength value and it should work fine

Comment: Thanks all. Just for reference if someone face this issue use below attribute 

[TypeConverter(typeof(GridLengthTypeConverter))]
public GridLength Width
{
    get => (GridLength)GetValue(WidthProperty);
    set => SetValue(WidthProperty, value);
}

Answer (score 0):

The MAUI do not support the `DataGrid`. Besides, you can not set the `DataGridColumn` to the Grid, because Grid do not have this Property.

It is recommended that you can change the DataGrid to the Grid. You can check this [Grid Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.grid?view=net-maui-8.0#properties) for more information.